# keep-alive inside v-for doesn't work when array length is changed

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to render a component from a computed value. But, when the array length changes from its previous length, then `<keep-alive>` tag doesn't work.

I expect the `cOption` component's created hook to only fire once, 
but it continues to log its "cOption created!" message each time the `flag` value is toggled to `false`.

I'm using Vue version ^2.5.13 (with Nuxt version 1.4.0)

Here's my code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      flag: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    options() {
      let opts = []
      if (this.flag) opts.push('aOption')
      else {
        opts.push('bOption', 'cOption')
      }
        
      return opts
    }
  },
  components: {
    defaultOption: {
      template: '<span>defaultOption</span>',
    },
    aOption: {
      template: '<span>aOption {{ flag }}</span>',
      props: {
        flag: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        }
      },
      created: function() {
        console.log("aOption created!")
      },
    },
    bOption: {
      template: '<span>bOption {{ flag }}</span>',
      props: {
        flag: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        }
      },
      created: function() {
        console.log("bOption created!")
      },
    },
    cOption: {
      template: '<span>cOption {{ flag }}</span>',
      props: {
        flag: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        }
      },
      created: function() {
        console.log("cOption created!")
      },
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>  
    <button @click='flag = !flag'>
        toggle option
    </button>
    <div v-for='option in options'>
        <keep-alive>
          <component :is='option' :flag='flag' :key='option' />
        </keep-alive>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a js fiddle of the above code](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/422807/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that when the `options` array changes from having two items to only having one, the second `<keep-alive>` tag and everything in it is destroyed. So then, when the array changes back to two items, the `<keep-alive>` component is created and so is the `<component>` inside of it.

You want to keep the `<keep-alive>` from getting destroyed. One simple way to do this would be to provide an empty string as a second item in the array when the `flag` value is `true`:

```
computed: {
  options() {
    return this.flag ? ['aOption', ''] : ['bOption', 'cOption'];
  }
}
```

This way, the `v-for` will keep that second `<keep-alive>` around, and the dynamic `<component>` just won't render anything.

---

Here's your code with that change:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { flag: false }
  },
  computed: {
     options() {
        return this.flag ? ['aOption', ''] : ['bOption', 'cOption'];
     }
  },
  components: {
    aOption: {
      template: '<span>aOption {{ flag }}</span>',
      props: {
        flag: { type: Boolean, default: false }
      },
      created: function() {
        console.log("aOption created!")
      },
    },
    bOption: {
      template: '<span>bOption {{ flag }}</span>',
      props: {
        flag: { type: Boolean, default: false }
      },
      created: function() {
        console.log("bOption created!")
      },
    },
    cOption: {
      template: '<span>cOption {{ flag }}</span>',
      props: {
        flag: { type: Boolean, default: false }
      },
      created: function() {
        console.log("cOption created!")
      },
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>  
    <button @click='flag = !flag'>toggle option</button>
    <div v-for='option in options'>
      <keep-alive>
        <component  :is='option' :flag='flag' :key='option' />
      </keep-alive>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it was so helpful :)